# how config WCF Service Behaviour

Tags: .net, wcf

In what way can config `ServiceBehaviour` in WCF for 2000 client per/min in WCF

```
instanceContextMode=? 
ConcurencyMode=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had very good results like this:

```
 ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
 InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall
```

We've done extensive testing of a BasicHTTPBinding WCF setup (self-hosted) and were able to >120 concurrent connections/second, all uploading and downloading files from the host.